# Place EditText/TextView Over MapView Android

Tags: android

I am building an app that needs a mapview and a textview to enable a place/location picker. It is to be like "uber" where the mapview fills the whole screen and then the editext views for choosing a location are superimposed on top of the map view. The issue is that my design xml file places the textviews "behind" the mapview so that they are covered by the map and not visible. How can i do it that they appear over the mapview ; while the mapview still covers 100% of the screen height?. My xml file is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Pickup Location"
    android:id="@+id/pickup"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Drop Location"
    android:id="@+id/drop"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/pickup"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ride_start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_below="@+id/drop"
    android:text="Start"/>
</LinearLayout>


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity"

    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#F8CA2B"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totaldistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#fff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cost"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set map fragement first then overlay of relative layout might be helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


     <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context="MainActivity"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Pickup Location"
        android:id="@+id/pickup"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Drop Location"
        android:id="@+id/drop"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/pickup"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ride_start"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drop"
        android:text="Start"/>
   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#F8CA2B"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totaldistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#fff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cost"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:circular="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/content_frame_child">
<!--Your map fragment-->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="MainActivity"/>
<!--Your map fragment ends--> 
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/info"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="#F8CA2B"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/totaldistance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:textColor="#000" />
<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="#fff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cost"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000" />
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Use frame layout for overlay

Comment: I'm using osmdroid and have replaced "Your map fragment" on org.osmdroid.views.MapView. It looks fine like an edittext component above the map. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pickup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Pickup Location"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/pickup"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Drop Location"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ride_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/drop"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="MainActivity"

            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/map"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="#F8CA2B"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totaldistance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textColor="#000" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textColor="#000" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks ysl i went with Vij's answer above because i saw it first. Thank you for your time